# Pygame: After I let go of the button action keeps on going

Tags: pygame

I have already made a few projects, but this time I ran into a problem.
I made a game type when the arrow goes across a bar and you click a button to stop it and you aim it as close to the middle.

The button you need to press is randomized (w, a, s, d). When a button comes 2 or more times in a row, the other times it stops the arrow in the first frame, like it was being pressed the whole time. It's the same when I am done with the arrow mini-game and I go to a 2D RPG like game. It keeps on moving in the direction that I last pressed like the button is stuck.

When I press it again it stops and I can move freely.

I can include the code if you want to look but it is long and complicated so I don't want to make you look through the whole thing if not necessary.
If you can help or have any questions write them down, thanks.

Edit:
I am including a part of the code in which the arrow mini-game is going on, if you want a full version it is about 200 lines. Thanks.

```
    while borba:
        if enemyhp<=0:
            break

        crtanjeploceborbe()
        crtanjeenemyhealthbar(enemyhp)
        crtanjeneprijatelja((300+500)/2-100/2,10,neprijateljnb)
        pygame.display.update()
        mis=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if mis[0]<fightbuttonpos[2] and mis[0]>fightbuttonpos[0] and mis[1]<fightbuttonpos[1] and mis[1]>fightbuttonpos[3]:                            
                    fightmeterx=random.randint(actionspaceavailablex[0]-1,actionspaceavailablex[1])
                    fightmetery=random.randint(actionspaceavailabley[0]-1,actionspaceavailabley[1])
                    button=random.choice(["w","a","s","d"])
                    poztipke=fightmeterx-45
                    brzinatipke=2.5
                    natezanje=True                   
                    while natezanje:

                        if poztipke>=fightmeterx+380-45:
                            poztipke=fightmeterx+380-45
                            pygame.time.wait(2500)
                            dmg=5
                            break
                        for event in pygame.event.get():

                            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                                if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                                    buttonpress="w"
                                elif event.key==pygame.K_a:
                                    buttonpress="a"
                                elif event.key==pygame.K_d:
                                    buttonpress="d"
                                elif event.key==pygame.K_s:
                                    buttonpress="s"
                            if buttonpress==button:

                                if poztipke+45<=fightmeterx+104 or poztipke>=fightmeterx+344:
                                    dmg=5
                                elif poztipke+45<=fightmeterx+190 or poztipke>=fightmeterx+302:
                                    dmg=10
                                elif poztipke+45<=fightmeterx+261: 
                                    dmg=20
                                else:
                                    dmg=40
                                pygame.time.wait(1500)
                                borba=True
                                natezanje=False         
                        crtanjeploceborbe()
                        crtanjeenemyhealthbar(enemyhp)
                        crtanjeneprijatelja((300+500)/2-100/2,10,neprijateljnb)
                        crtanjefightmetera(fightmeterx,fightmetery)
                        if button == "w":
                            crtanjewtipke(poztipke,fightmetery-90)
                        elif button == "a":
                            crtanjeatipke(poztipke,fightmetery-90)
                        elif button == "s":
                            crtanjestipke(poztipke,fightmetery-90)
                        else:
                            crtanjedtipke(poztipke,fightmetery-90)
                        pygame.display.update()
                        brzinatipke=brzinatipke*1.015
                        poztipke+=brzinatipke
                    enemyhp-=dmg
```

Comment: Would it possible for you to include a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rather than you whole code?

Comment: if not for anything else you should not be looping through the events (returned by `pygament.event.get` inside _another_ loop through the same events.

Comment: Are you sure this code is indented correctly?  It does nothing if there is not a mouse-button-down event.  Did you try handling `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP` and setting `button = None`.  Perhaps temporarily removing the random-button part would help you debug.

Comment: the first comment about not doing anything when there is no mousebuttondown: that is  when you press a button to start the minigame.

Comment: thx for the tips I will try them and report back

Comment: omfg i am so stupid. I never change back the pressed button. the removing randomising part rly helped. thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

I never change back the pressed button so it remembers the button pressed from the last minigame(loop)

Answer (score 0):

Hello leon lukacevic,

I suggest adding `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP` with the required action, this will solve  your issue.
Not related to your question, but you called `for event in pygame.event.get()` again inside the loop. This may create a problem in the future.
Please click the tick if you found my answer helpful :) Thanks